# How the local instance is not reset during an recursive call in python

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I was practicing a problem to find the nth number of a Fibonacci series using dynamic programming.
Here is my python code:

```
def fib(n,memo=[1,1]):
    if n<=len(memo):
        return memo[n-1]
    else:
        memo.append(fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))
        return memo[n-1]
print(fib(100))
```

Here I didn't passed the second parameter memo to the recursive calls of the function fib. But still I works.

I am wondering how python doesn't reset to the default parameter value of memo.

Can anyone explain about this?

I actually introduced a print statement before the if statement to print the value of memo list.
It is actually storing the result of the recursive calls.
But how can it actually store the value when I didn't pass that memo parameter.
It can store the memo instance if the recursive statement was like.

```
memo.append(fib(n-1,memo)+fib(n-2,memo)
```

Comment: this looks like it is working.  what were you expecting ?

Comment: I want to know how the memo list is not reset to its default value i.e, [1,1] as I didn't pass memo as argument in the recursive calls. In other languages it works when we pass the memo as argument in the recursive calls.

Comment: a good question: it is the difference between mutable an immutable variables. The memo is a list which is mutable and when you append the list it grows the list, but the code is still pointing to the same list in memory space.  Here is a video i made a while ago, which has the similar list as argument structure.  https://youtu.be/n-K56SLJ4vY

Comment: Good reference - https://florimond.dev/en/posts/2018/08/python-mutable-defaults-are-the-source-of-all-evil/

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my comment, a good explanation can be demonstrated by modifying the code to this:

```py
def fib(n,memo:list=[1,1]):
    if n<=len(memo):
        return memo[n-1]
    else:
        memo.append(fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))
        print(id(memo), len(memo))
        return memo[n-1]

print(fib(10))
```

We print the memory location (`id`) and the size of the list in the `print` statement.

The result is this:

```
1882310540544 3
1882310540544 4
1882310540544 5
1882310540544 6
1882310540544 7
1882310540544 8
1882310540544 9
1882310540544 10
```

the memory location of the list is the same each time (i.e. it is the same list). And the list is growing in size (for each append) !

This is effectively what is happening.

(lists are mutable).

Comment: Yeah, you're correct.but what I found difficult is in other programing language you've to pass the current list as an argument to the recursive function call to append to the existing list otherwise it will always consider the default parameter in the function definition inside the function.

Comment: it depends on the language. In python, there is a concept of `mutable` and `immutable`. You might consider `mutable` and being a `pointer` in c++ or passing `by reference` in vba....  so each language has their own way (ultimately the same objective). Once you understand it, the system is very logical and i fact very convenient.